# Issue with upload file from device

Tags: codenameone

I am using this code to upload an file from device Andriod & IOS. It works on emulator but not working with devices

My code is

```
if (FileChooser.isAvailable()) {
    FileChooser.showOpenDialog(
        ".pdf, application/pdf, .gif, image/gif, .png, image/png, .jpg, image/jpg, .tif, image/tif, .jpeg, .bmp", 
        e2-> {
        if(e2!=null && e2.getSource()!=null) {
            String file = (String)e2.getSource();
            String filestack = URL restfull web service 
            MultipartRequest request = new MultipartRequest(); 
            request.setUrl(filestack);
            request.setPost(true);
            request.addData("fileUpload", file, "*/*");
            request.setFilename("fileUpload", fileName);
            request.setReadResponseForErrors(true);
            NetworkManager.getInstance().addToQueueAndWait(request);
        }
}
```

The exception is

```
file///data/user/0/com.xxx.yyyy/files/image  
(No such file or directory) this message appear when trace this line
request.addData("fileUpload", file, "*/*");
```

please help with this issue
thanks

Comment: The file path returned on the device doesn't contain an actual file URL for some reason. How did you pick the file on the device?

Comment: By using FileChooser.showOpenDialog and then get the full file path by this String file = (String)e2.getSource().We are used this around 2 years ago with our HR mobile application  with codenameone, I think this not working before update the lib

Comment: It was working before the update but now is still not working, please help with this issue, we are a compnay and there is many users used ths app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue is fixed in Git.  It will be included in the next server update (on Friday). 
https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/commit/e0b650adcb485894e9bc249ebac780bac40eb22a

Comment: Thanks for replay, we will be waiting.

Answer (score 0):

You can see the older version of the lib in the repo: https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOneLibs/tree/master/cn1libs

You can download and install the older version manually by replacing the existing binary and using refresh libs.

If this is indeed a regression in the lib please file an issue with screenshots/code from before/after in the issue tracker here: http://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/issues/new

Comment: Thanks for replay but did you mean all lib or FileChooser only because the exception for these lines MultipartRequest request = new MultipartRequest(); 
request.setUrl(filestack);
request.setPost(true);
request.addData("fileUpload", file, "/");
request.setFilename("fileUpload", fileName);
request.setReadResponseForErrors(true); NetworkManager.getInstance().addToQueueAndWait(request);

Comment: I have updated 3 libs CN1FileChooser & CN1JSON & Connectivity but still the same, could you please check my code a bove